# How to Extract Json value from an array based on some value in sub array

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I want to get the `"id":1922` from the main array based on the `"id":1` from the sub array 'media_type':

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1922,
         "media_count":1,
         "title":"test",
         "description":"Test",
         "address":null,
         "latitude":null,
         "longitude":null,
         "privacy":1,
         "license":1,
         "is_comment_disable":0,
         "is_adult":0,
         "media_type":{
            "id":1,
            "slug":"photo",
            "title":"Photo"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting json to object, you can use json parser
For reference: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.json.stream.JsonParser

Comment: need to get this is in jmeter using jmeter provided elements like reg ex or Json extractor or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSON path to get value base on media_type

`$..data[?(@.media_type>0)].id`

Comment: worked with "$..data[?(@.media_type.id==1)].id". Thanks

Comment: based on JSON you provided so I just use media_type>0